# Android Databinding fails to create static fields in BR.java for variables from external library

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, android-library

I have created an Android library (aar) that contains some fragments that make use of databinding, by using `<data>` tag inside xml layout components. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="type"
            type="String" />
        <variable
            name="letter"
            type="String" />
        <variable
            name="color"
            type="Integer" />
        <variable
            name="confirmTaskButtonListener"
            type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView>
        ...
    </ScrollView>

</layout>
```

When I assemble the aar, I can correctly see, under generated-classes, `BR.java` that contains a static field for each variable declared for binding.

When I use the aar as dependency in an Android application, instead, `BR.java` is rebuilt and it does not contain static fields for variables declared in the parent library.
This is not a problem at compile time. But, at runtime, fragments from library reference static fields that are not present in BR of the child application and causes a crash.

How can I manage to build in the child application static fields also for databindings declared in the parent library?

I have enabled databinding in both application and library modules:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

I am using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'`.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: post whole your layout file. Most of the time it happen because of an error in that xml.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue.
The problem was that the **package names** of the app and of the library were the same.

As I've changed package name on the library, it started working.

Thank you!